# What test to use to measure independence in 2x2 matrix with large numbers?

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence, large-data

I measured the amount of times men/women reacted to posts made by men/women.
I want to know if men reacted more often to women (or other way around?).

I have the following data:

[image: Table I created]

So if a man posted something, and another man reacted to it, I would count +1 in the column where it says 252255.

I first thought to use the Chi-Squared Test, but I got an insanely big Chi Squared value out of this (77258), so it seemd like that wasn't the right test.

Does anyone know what test to use for something like this?

Comment: With that sample size you are almost bound to find that any difference, however small, is statistically significant. You might want to use a measure of association with its confidence interval instead.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with its confidence interval? Im not that familiar within statistics

Comment: Isn't the answer incredibly obvious?  There's a huge difference in the response rates and you have hundreds of thousands of observations. *Of course* any statistical test is going to give an "insanely big" statistic!